# Background margin fill for (first line of) section titles?

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning, formatting, thumb-index

I'd like some of those "flaps" (how are these really called in typography, actually? Is it "thumb index"?) which is a bit of fill, extending to the margin; so that when you "bend" a book, you can see more easily where a section is - something similar to:

- [Color background for chapter titles which stretches horizontally to the margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146443/color-background-for-chapter-titles-which-stretches-horizontally-to-the-margins)
- [Chapter Title in rotated vertical box at the margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48641/chapter-title-in-rotated-vertical-box-at-the-margin)

... except for sections - so something like [Vertical color background of section title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199732/vertical-color-background-of-section-title), except for only the first line of the section (or in general, a fill with a fixed width, aligned with the first line of the section).

I thought I could use `tikz` for this, so I prepared this MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\titleformat*{\section}{%
  \normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{black!90}%
  \tikzexternaldisable%
  %\tikz\node(AA){A};% ! Package titlesec Error: Entered in horizontal mode.
  \tikzexternalenable%
}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\mainmatter

\part{Introduction}
\chapter*{The first chapter - without thinking anything else}

\section{The first section - and some more text inside; and some more text inside; and some more text inside}

Blah, blah, blah...

\end{document}
```

The output - along with my desired effect, which I've helpfully `:)` indicated in red - looks like this (click for full res):

[image: test.png]

As the source notes, as soon as I start putting in `\tikz\node(AA){A};` nodes for testing, I get `! Package titlesec Error: Entered in horizontal mode.`.

Is this possible to solve, without having to include the `tikzmark` or `tikzpagenodes` packages?

As a subquestion, is it possible to solve so that the "flap" extends from the section to the outer paper edge - regardless if the section ends up on left-hand or right-hand page? (I'm still primarily interested in a "complete" line margin-to-margin, except with a break along `\textwidth` - which implies two rectangle nodes)...

Comment: What is the `A`?

Comment: Thanks @cfr - the `A` is just a dummy text I entered for testing, when I first starting getting errors for empty node text `{};` - I should have removed it, but nevermind now...

Comment: Why don't you want to use `tikzpagenodes` or `tikzmark`? Any particular reason to avoid making life easier for yourself?

Comment: Thanks again @cfr - I am kind of guessing they'd be applicable here... I was thinking, if the solution is trivial enough, I'd prefer not including them, as I already include a ton of packages in my (real) doc; but if it is much easier, then certainly I'd go along with a solution using them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to use `tikzpagenodes`, you could use something like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{black!90}}{\thesection}{1.5em}{\tikzexternaldisable\sectioncolouration{A}}[\tikzexternalenable]

\newcommand*\sectioncolouration[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.base), overlay, remember picture, inner xsep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \node  (a) {\phantom{\normalfont\Large\bfseries Xy}};
    \path [fill=blue, fill opacity=.2, even odd rule] (current page.west |- a.north) -| (current page.east |- a.south) -| cycle (current page text area.west |- a.north) -| (current page text area.east |- a.south) -| cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
  \frontmatter
  \mainmatter

  \part{Introduction}
  \chapter*{The first chapter - without thinking anything else}

  \section{The first section - and some more text inside; and some more text inside; and some more text inside}

  Blah, blah, blah...

\end{document}
```

[image: colouration of section to margins]

## EDIT

Here's a version that adds an alphabetical marker corresponding to the section:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external,calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{black!90}}{\thesection}{1.5em}{\tikzexternaldisable\sectioncolouration{\Alph{section}}}[\tikzexternalenable]

\newcommand*\sectioncolouration[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.base), overlay, remember picture, inner xsep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \node  (a) {\phantom{\normalfont\Large\bfseries Xy}};
    \path [fill=blue, fill opacity=.2, even odd rule] (current page.west |- a.north) -| (current page.east |- a.south) -| cycle (current page text area.west |- a.north) -| (current page text area.east |- a.south) -| cycle;
    \ifodd\value{page}
    \node at (a -| {$(current page text area.east)!1/2!(current page.east)$}) {#1};
    \else
    \node at (a -| {$(current page text area.west)!1/2!(current page.west)$}) {#1};
    \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
  \frontmatter
  \mainmatter

  \part{Introduction}
  \chapter*{The first chapter - without thinking anything else}

  \newpage

  \section{The first section - and some more text inside; and some more text inside; and some more text inside}

  Blah, blah, blah...

  \newpage
  \section{This section starts on an even page}
  Some text\dots

\end{document}
```

[image: alphabetical markers]

Comment: @sdaau Thanks! See edit, too. I forgot to do anything with the argument in the first version, as I wasn't sure what the goal was. But this shows how to use it, at least ;).

Answer (score 1):

The solution from @cfr is great, but since I was working on this, I'll post an alternate solution; it is based on:

- [Rotate text in Thumbindex using thumbs package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195807/rotate-text-in-thumbindex-using-thumbs-package)

... with the trick that I'm using `\vadjust` ([How to switch between horizontal and vertical modes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125557/how-to-switch-between-horizontal-and-vertical-modes)) to get rid of that "Entered in horizontal mode" (Note that it is manually tuned in respect to widths etc, so as such the solutions from @cfr are much better):

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}

\newcommand{\tikzmarkS}[1]{\tikz[overlay, remember picture]\coordinate(#1){};}

\titleformat*{\section}{%
  \normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{black!90}%
  \tikzexternaldisable%
  %\tikz\node(AA){A};% ! Package titlesec Error: Entered in horizontal mode.
  \tikzmarkS{s\arabic{section}}\typeout{s\arabic{section}}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \typeout{s\arabic{section}}
  \node[rotate=90,minimum width=\baselineskip,minimum height=5.6cm,fill=gray!30,text=white,anchor=south west] at ([yshift=-1.35\baselineskip]s\arabic{section}-|current page.north east) {\arabic{section}};
  \node[rotate=90,minimum width=\baselineskip,minimum height=3.6cm,fill=gray!30,text=white,anchor=north east] at ([yshift=-0.28\baselineskip]s\arabic{section}-|current page.south west) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \vadjust%
  \tikzexternalenable%
}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\mainmatter

\part{Introduction}
\chapter*{The first chapter - without thinking anything else}

\section{The first section - and some more text inside; and some more text inside; and some more text inside}
% can be used outside of section, too:
% \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
% \typeout{s\arabic{section}}
% \node[rotate=90,minimum width=\baselineskip,minimum height=3cm,fill=gray!30,font=\large\bfseries,text=white,anchor=south west] at ([yshift=-2em]s\arabic{section}-|current page.north east) {\arabic{section}};
% \end{tikzpicture}%


Blah, blah, blah...

\end{document}
```

... and the output is (click for full res):

[image: test.png]