# Using tikzpagenodes with crop package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, crop, tikzpagenodes

Using the code from [Background margin fill for (first line of) section titles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235776/background-margin-fill-for-first-line-of-section-titles/235780#235780), I have this MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage[
  paperwidth=15cm,
  paperheight=20cm,
  outer=2.5cm,
  inner=2.5cm,
  top=2.5cm,
  bottom=2.5cm
  ]{geometry}
% \usepackage[a4,center]{crop}   % `crop` line
% \crop[cam,info]                % `crop` line

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external,calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{black!90}}{\thesection}{1.5em}{\tikzexternaldisable\sectioncolouration{\Alph{section}}}[\tikzexternalenable]

\newcommand*\sectioncolouration[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.base), overlay, remember picture, inner xsep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \node  (a) {\phantom{\normalfont\Large\bfseries Xy}};
    \path [fill=blue, fill opacity=.2, even odd rule] (current page.west |- a.north) -| (current page.east |- a.south) -| cycle (current page text area.west |- a.north) -| (current page text area.east |- a.south) -| cycle;
    \ifodd\value{page}
    \node at (a -| {$(current page text area.east)!1/2!(current page.east)$}) {#1};
    \else
    \node at (a -| {$(current page text area.west)!1/2!(current page.west)$}) {#1};
    \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
  \frontmatter
  \mainmatter

  \part{Introduction}
  \chapter*{The first chapter - without thinking anything else}

  \newpage

  \section{The first section - and some more text inside; and some more text inside; and some more text inside}

  Blah, blah, blah...

  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw[thick] (current page text area.north east) rectangle (current page text area.south west) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \newpage
  \section{This section starts on an even page}
  Some text\dots

\end{document}
```

With the `crop` lines commented, as posted, everything is fine (after texing twice - click for full res):

[image: test.png]

But if I uncomment the `crop` lines, and recompile, then the output is corrupt:

[image: test1.png]

It's as if `current page text area` (and even `\ifodd\value{page}`) cannot be determined if crop is active?!

Is there any way to get this code to work, even if `crop` is active?

Comment: You are using a custom paper size?

Comment: Thanks @cfr: Yes, I am - I shuffled the values shown in this MWE a bit, just to "genericize", but I still have a custom paper size in my actual doc...

Comment: You need to tell `geometry`. It thinks that your paper is 15x20cm when it is really 21x29.7cm. However, I'm losing the crop marks when I do this.

Comment: You know that `geometry` has a `showcrop` of its own? That works fine...

Comment: Thanks for that @cfr - good to know about the problems with `geometry` and losing cropmarks; had no idea about `geometry`'s `showcrop` - but I'd prefer to get this working with the `crop` package (it was used in the original template I'm using).

Comment: I have to say: I've never answered a question this often before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a third answer. As the image shows, this does not correct the placement of the nodes added by `tikzpagenodes`. Rather, it compensates for the lies `crop` tells within the limited context of the section thumbs configuration.

[image: section thumbs despite the lies]

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage[
  paperwidth=15cm,
  paperheight=20cm,
  outer=2.5cm,
  inner=2.5cm,
  top=2.5cm,
  bottom=2.5cm
  ]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,center]{crop}   % `crop` line
\crop[cam,info]                % `crop` line

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external,calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{black!90}}{\thesection}{1.5em}{\tikzexternaldisable\sectioncolouration{\Alph{section}}}[\tikzexternalenable]

\newcommand*\sectioncolouration[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.base), overlay, remember picture, inner xsep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \node  (a) {\phantom{\normalfont\Large\bfseries Xy}};
    \ifx\stockwidth\undefined
    \coordinate (b) at (0,0);
    \else
    \coordinate (b) at (.5\paperwidth-.5\stockwidth,.5\stockheight-.5\paperheight);
    \fi
    \begin{scope}
      \path [fill=blue, fill opacity=.2, even odd rule] (current page.west |- a.north) -| (current page.east |- a.south) -| cycle ({$(current page text area.west) + (b)$} |- a.north) -| ({$(current page text area.east) + (b)$} |- a.south) -| cycle;
      \ifodd\value{page}
      \node at (a -| {$(current page text area.east)!1/2!(current page.east) + .5*(b)$}) {#1};
      \else
      \node at (a -| {$(current page text area.west)!1/2!(current page.west) + .5*(b)$}) {#1};
      \fi
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
  \frontmatter
  \mainmatter

  \part{Introduction}
  \chapter*{The first chapter - without thinking anything else}

  \newpage

  \section{The first section - and some more text inside; and some more text inside; and some more text inside}

  Blah, blah, blah...

  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw[thick] (current page text area.north east) rectangle (current page text area.south west) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \newpage
  \section{This section starts on an even page}
  Some text\dots

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @cfr - I like this one the best; I just added an `\ifx` conditional, so the same code works if just the `crop` lines are commented. Btw, I also tried to work with `\stockwidth`, but as it can be seen from my answer below, couldn't really figure it out, so I took a different approach (via redef of top and left). Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau Note that this relies on the fact that you are passing `center` to `crop`, I think. Otherwise, you'd need to adjust the `0.5` appropriately in defining `(b)`.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think I have something, but am not exactly sure of it; the fix seems to be this:

```
\ifx\CROP@size\undefined
  \typeout{CROP@size undefined}
\else
  \typeout{CROP@size defined}
  % must set via newlength so it survives descent into tikzpicture!
  \setlength\gparindent{\parindent}
  \setlength\gbaselineskip{\baselineskip}
  \def\current@textarea@left{(1in+\hoffset+\currentsidemargin-\Gm@lmargin-\gparindent)}
  \def\current@textarea@top{(1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep)+2*\Gm@tmargin-0.35\gbaselineskip}
\fi
```

... that is, if `crop` is loaded, redefine `\current@textarea@left` and `\current@textarea@top` from `tikzpagenodes`, so the left is adjusted by `\Gm@lmargin-\gparindent` and the right by `2*\Gm@tmargin-0.35\gbaselineskip` - where `\Gm@l`/`tmargin` are margins via the `geometry` package.

The `\gparindent` and `\gbaselineskip` are "globalised" versions of parindent/baselineskip - as lengths - otherwise they won't propagate when the above definitions run inside `tikzpicture` (which resets parindent/baselineskip). The Gm@ margins make sense, but I have no idea why there is this displacement in there to begin with - I found the fix values via trial/error, so caveat emptor.

The code below has some extra debug stuff, and it outputs something like this:

[image: /tmp/test.png]

Seems there is a tiny amount of bleed too - which is nice; also, all seems to work if you just comment the `crop` lines, as well.

The code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage[
  paperwidth=15cm,
  paperheight=20cm,
  outer=3.5cm,
  inner=2.5cm,
  top=2.5cm,
  bottom=3.5cm
  ]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,center]{crop}
\crop[cam,info]

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external,calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\makeatletter
\newlength\gparindent
\newlength\gbaselineskip
\ifx\CROP@size\undefined
  \typeout{CROP@size undefined}
\else
  \typeout{CROP@size defined}
  % from tikzpagenodes:
  % NB: \parindent, \baselineskip seem to dissapear inside \sectioncolouration
%   \let\gparindent\parindent% NO
%   \xdef\gparindent{\parindent}% NO!
  % must set via newlength so it survives descent into tikzpicture!
  \setlength\gparindent{\parindent}
  \setlength\gbaselineskip{\baselineskip}
  \typeout{gparindent-Start \the\gparindent}%
  \def\current@textarea@left{(1in+\hoffset+\currentsidemargin-\Gm@lmargin-\gparindent)}
  \def\current@textarea@top{(1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep)+2*\Gm@tmargin-0.35\gbaselineskip}
  % no need to repeat this:
%   \@newtikzpagenode{current page text area}{%
%     \def\southwest{\pgfpoint{\current@textarea@left}{\paperheight-\current@textarea@top-\textheight}}%
%     \def\northeast{\pgfpoint{\current@textarea@left+\textwidth}{\paperheight-\current@textarea@top}}%
%   }
\fi
\makeatother


\newcommand*\sectioncolouration[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.base), overlay, remember picture, inner xsep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]%
    \typeout{gparindent-In-Sect-Col \the\gparindent}%
    \node  (a) {\phantom{\normalfont\Large\bfseries Xy}};
    \path [fill=blue, fill opacity=.2, even odd rule]
      (current page.west |- a.north) -| (current page.east |- a.south) -| cycle
      (current page text area.west |- a.north) -| (current page text area.east |- a.south) -| cycle;
%     (current page text area.south west) -| (current page text area.north east) -| cycle; % debug
    \draw[red] (current page text area.north east) rectangle (current page text area.south west); % debug
    \ifodd\value{page}
    \node at (a -| {$(current page text area.east)!1/2!(current page.east)$}) {#1};
    \else
    \node at (a -| {$(current page text area.west)!1/2!(current page.west)$}) {#1};
    \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{%
  \typeout{gparindent-Sect \the\gparindent}%
  \setlength\gparindent{\parindent}%
  \setlength\gbaselineskip{\baselineskip}%
  \normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{black!90}%
}{\thesection}{1.5em}{\tikzexternaldisable\sectioncolouration{\Alph{section}}}[\tikzexternalenable]


\begin{document}
  \frontmatter
  \mainmatter


  \part{Introduction}
  \chapter*{The first chapter - without thinking anything else}

  \newpage

  \section{The first section - and some more text inside; and some more text inside; and some more text inside}

  % debug
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw[thick] (current page text area.north east) rectangle (current page text area.south west) ;
  \draw[thick] (current page text area.east) rectangle ($(current page text area.west)+(0,1)$) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \noindent
  Blah, blah, blah... \lipsum[1-3]

%   \newpage
  \section{This section starts on an odd page}
  Some text\dots

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`crop` appears to fundamentally disagree with `tikzpagenodes`. Or, rather, lying about your page layout, as `crop` requires, appears to fundamentally disagree with it. This is not terribly surprising. If the text area is not where you say, it isn't that surprising that things go haywire.

If `geometry`'s crop marks are an option, these work fine:

[image: crop marks with fancy sections]

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[
  paper=a4paper,
  layoutsize={15cm,20cm},
  layoutoffset={30mm,48.5mm},
  outer=2.5cm,
  inner=2.5cm,
  top=2.5cm,
  bottom=2.5cm,
  showcrop,
  ]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external,calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{black!90}}{\thesection}{1.5em}{\tikzexternaldisable\sectioncolouration{\Alph{section}}}[\tikzexternalenable]

\newcommand*\sectioncolouration[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.base), overlay, remember picture, inner xsep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \node  (a) {\phantom{\normalfont\Large\bfseries Xy}};
    \path [fill=blue, fill opacity=.2, even odd rule] (current page.west |- a.north) -| (current page.east |- a.south) -| cycle (current page text area.west |- a.north) -| (current page text area.east |- a.south) -| cycle;
    \ifodd\value{page}
    \node at (a -| {$(current page text area.east)!1/2!(current page.east)$}) {#1};
    \else
    \node at (a -| {$(current page text area.west)!1/2!(current page.west)$}) {#1};
    \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
  \frontmatter
  \mainmatter

  \part{Introduction}
  \chapter*{The first chapter - without thinking anything else}

  \newpage

  \section{The first section - and some more text inside; and some more text inside; and some more text inside}

  Blah, blah, blah...

  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[thick] (current page text area.north east) rectangle (current page text area.south west) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \newpage
  \section{This section starts on an even page}
  Some text\dots

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for that @cfr; I'm trying to mess a bit with redefining `tikzpagenodes` if `crop` is loaded (I'm not progressing much though); if everything else fails, I'll eventually accept this answer... Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on this problem from a more general angle.

From scanning the documentation of the `crop` package, it would seem like the most relevant values that we'd want to pull out are `\stockwidth` and `\stockheight`, which are used to store the ultimate paper size.

All we really need to do is redefine the main macros for `tikzpagenodes` to account for the difference between `\stock*` and `\paper*`. The code for this is

```
\def\current@textarea@left{%
  (1in+\hoffset+\currentsidemargin+.5*(\paperwidth-\stockwidth))%
}
\def\current@textarea@top{%
  (1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep-.5*(\stockheight-\paperheight))%
}
```

Which just adds half of the difference between the `\stock` and `\paper` values to acccount for the offset. We only need half the value b/c the logical page is centered in the physical page, thus offset by half the difference.

To make a generic version of this, we'll do the following:

```
%fix the crop issue with tikzpagenodes
\@ifpackageloaded{crop}{
  \@ifpackagewith{crop}{center}
    {
    \def\current@textarea@left{%
      (1in+\hoffset+\currentsidemargin+.5*(\paperwidth-\stockwidth))}
    \def\current@textarea@top{%
      (1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep-.5*(\stockheight-\paperheight))}
    }
    {
    \def\current@textarea@top{%
      (1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep-(\stockheight-\paperheight))}
    }
  }
  {%
}
```

Now we can automatically adjust for the offset if the crop package is loaded. I also made a different adjustment for when the `center` option isn't used, where the `\hoffset` is fine and thus doesn't need adjustment, and the `\voffset` needs twice the adjustment (seeing as we're at the top left corner of the page).

I tested this both while typesetting RTL and LTR texts, using XeTeX.

It's actually interesting, because the `center` option actually sets `\hoffset` and `\voffset` to values which would be correct for our needs, but investigating that isn't necessary.