# Using titleformat* with tikzpicture (leaving horizontal mode)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, titlesec

I'd like to use the same code as in [Using tikzpagenodes with crop package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235787/using-tikzpagenodes-with-crop-package/235807#235807) - except with `\titleformat*`, not with `\titleformat`. Why? Because in the original code I got with the template for my real doc has just (say):

```
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{gray}}
```

... and I'd like to add the thumb index without significantly changing that code or its output; and for `\titleformat` I need to know if shape is `[hang]`, and what the { sep } argument is, before I can replicate correctly - and I have no idea how to retrieve those values.

So with the change to `\titleformat*` in the MWE below, I get:

```
! Package titlesec Error: Entered in horizontal mode.
```

... but if I keep pressing ENTER, the doc compiles, and it is seemingly what I want (though possibly not the same as the `\titleformat` output); on the image (click for full res), left is the `\titleformat*`, right is the `\titleformat`:

[image: /tmp/test.png]

Via this post: [tikzpicture without leaving vertical mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15769/tikzpicture-without-leaving-vertical-mode) , I got to the following - it looks related to me, but I'm not sure:

> I think the problem is not that TeX leaves vertical mode - if you capture the content into a \vbox, the "leave vertical mode" command is restricted locally to that box.

Yes, but if I do:

```
\titleformat*{\section}{%
\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{gray}%
\tikzexternaldisable%
\vbox{\sectioncolouration{\Alph{section}}}%
\tikzexternalenable%
}
```

... then a new line is inserted; and

> ...  I succeeded when I used \nointerlineskip in front of it.

... I tried `\nointerlineskip`, it didn't seem to work. The only thing not inserting a new line seems to be `\vbox to 0pt {\sectioncolouration{\Alph{section}}}` but then that messes up the layout in a different way.

So - how can I use a `\titleformat*` with a `tikzpicture` without getting the "horizontal mode" error? Alternately, how does one "leave" horizontal mode without artefacts (for some reason, there is no `\leavehmode`, only `\leavevmode`)?

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage[
  paperwidth=15cm,
  paperheight=20cm,
  outer=2.5cm,
  inner=2.5cm,
  top=2.5cm,
  bottom=2.5cm
  ]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,center]{crop}   % `crop` line
\crop[cam,info]                % `crop` line

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external,calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
%\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}

% \titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{black!90}}{\thesection}{1.5em}{\tikzexternaldisable\sectioncolouration{\Alph{section}}}[\tikzexternalenable]
\titleformat*{\section}{%
\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{gray}%
\tikzexternaldisable%
\vbox{\sectioncolouration{\Alph{section}}}%
\tikzexternalenable%
}

\newcommand*\sectioncolouration[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.base), overlay, remember picture, inner xsep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \node  (a) {\phantom{\normalfont\Large\bfseries Xy}};
    \ifx\stockwidth\undefined
    \coordinate (b) at (0,0);
    \else
    \coordinate (b) at (.5\paperwidth-.5\stockwidth,.5\stockheight-.5\paperheight);
    \fi
    \begin{scope}
      \path [fill=blue, fill opacity=.2, even odd rule] (current page.west |- a.north) -| (current page.east |- a.south) -| cycle ({$(current page text area.west) + (b)$} |- a.north) -| ({$(current page text area.east) + (b)$} |- a.south) -| cycle;
      \ifodd\value{page}
      \node at (a -| {$(current page text area.east)!1/2!(current page.east) + .5*(b)$}) {#1};
      \else
      \node at (a -| {$(current page text area.west)!1/2!(current page.west) + .5*(b)$}) {#1};
      \fi
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
  \frontmatter
  \mainmatter

  \part{Introduction}
  \chapter*{The first chapter - without thinking anything else}

  \newpage

  \section{The first section - and some more text inside; and some more text inside; and some more text inside}

  Blah, blah, blah...

  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw[thick] (current page text area.north east) rectangle (current page text area.south west) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \newpage
  \section{This section starts on an even page}
  Some text\dots

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, `\par` is technically a `\leavehmode`, but it's not what you're looking for I'm afraid.

Comment: Since `\titleformat*` has limitations, why don't you use `\titleformat`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you don't want to use `\titleformat`, given the limitations of `\titleformat*`.

Well, here's a way:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage[
  paperwidth=15cm,
  paperheight=20cm,
  outer=2.5cm,
  inner=2.5cm,
  top=2.5cm,
  bottom=2.5cm
  ]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,center]{crop}   % `crop` line
\crop[cam,info]                % `crop` line

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external,calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
%\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}

% \titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{black!90}}{\thesection}{1.5em}{\tikzexternaldisable\sectioncolouration{\Alph{section}}}[\tikzexternalenable]
\titleformat*{\section}{%
  \normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{gray}%
  \tikzexternaldisable%
  \toks0=\expandafter{\the\everypar}%
  \everypar={\sectioncolouration{\Alph{section}}\everypar=\toks0}%
  \tikzexternalenable%
}

\newcommand*\sectioncolouration[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.base), overlay, remember picture, inner xsep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \node  (a) {\phantom{\normalfont\Large\bfseries Xy}};
    \ifx\stockwidth\undefined
    \coordinate (b) at (0,0);
    \else
    \coordinate (b) at (.5\paperwidth-.5\stockwidth,.5\stockheight-.5\paperheight);
    \fi
    \begin{scope}
      \path [fill=blue, fill opacity=.2, even odd rule] (current page.west |- a.north) -| (current page.east |- a.south) -| cycle ({$(current page text area.west) + (b)$} |- a.north) -| ({$(current page text area.east) + (b)$} |- a.south) -| cycle;
      \ifodd\value{page}
      \node at (a -| {$(current page text area.east)!1/2!(current page.east) + .5*(b)$}) {#1};
      \else
      \node at (a -| {$(current page text area.west)!1/2!(current page.west) + .5*(b)$}) {#1};
      \fi
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
  \frontmatter
  \mainmatter

  \part{Introduction}
  \chapter*{The first chapter - without thinking anything else}

  \newpage

  \section{The first section - and some more text inside; and some more text inside; and some more text inside}

  Blah, blah, blah...

  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw[thick] (current page text area.north east) rectangle (current page text area.south west) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \newpage
  \section{This section starts on an even page}
  Some text\dots

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) That's really horrible ;).