# Precise positionning of a fullpage image when using zwpagelayout

Tags: tikz-pgf, includegraphics, zwpagelayout

I'm trying to insert a fullpage picture into a document taking into account a 3mm bleed. I've used the zwpagelaout package to setup my page and tikz to position / scale the image. I'm able to draw a rectangle at the right position with the right size but the image is not positioned correctly for some reason. Image `background.png` size is 1819 × 2551 pixels at 300dpi which corresponds to 154mmx216mm.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a5, margins=0mm, croplength=10mm,
                cropgap=3mm, cropmarks, cropframe]{zwpagelayout}
% \usepackage{fgruler}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

% This not positioned correctly
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, shift={(current page.north west)}]
  \node[anchor=north west,xshift=-3mm,yshift=-3mm]{
    \includegraphics[width=154mm]{background.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}

% This is positioned correctly
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.south west)}]
  \draw[black,xshift=-3mm,yshift=-3mm] (0mm,0mm) rectangle (154mm,216mm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**
Adding `inner sep=0pt` seems to fix the x positioning, and the "right" `y shift` seems to be -23mm that corresponds to 2xcroplength+3mm.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a [known problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235787/47927) that `crop` (which is used in the `zwpagelayout` package) messes up with `current page`. I tried to draw a rectangle connecting all four `current page` corners and it seems that the south west corner of this rectangle sits at the right place, but the north east corner sits far off outside the actual paper, which results in wrong placement of the picture if you anchor it to the north or east.

As you already found that using `current page.south west` as anchor seems to work, you could just anchor the image to this coordinate as well. Further, it is probably a bit more straighforward to position the node that includes the image directy without shifting the whole `tikzpicture`. Also, you should of course set the `inner sep` of the node to zero. The following should be working:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a5, margins=0mm, croplength=10mm,
                cropgap=3mm, cropmarks, cropframe]{zwpagelayout}
% \usepackage{fgruler}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

% This should be positioned correctly
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt, xshift=-3mm, yshift=-3mm] at (current page.south west) {\includegraphics[width=154mm]{background.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result should then be something like this:

[image]