# Easiest alternatives for thumb-index indicators on chapters in a book?

Tags: packages, thumb-index

I have earlier asked [Background margin fill for (first line of) section titles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235776/background-margin-fill-for-first-line-of-section-titles), but I have a different problem now. I have a document that can be approximated with this MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[fixpdftex,cmyk,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{black}}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries\color{black}}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\color{black}}
% Modify how \chapter, \section, etc. look
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}} % removes the chapter number in front! restored by \numberwithin{section}{chapter}
\numberwithin{section}{chapter}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\part{Part one}
\chapter{Chapter one}
\section{Section one}
\subsection{subSection one}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

I Simply want a thumb-index indicator/"flap?" positioned to the right of each "Chapter" heading, black background possibly with a white part.chapter number inside; printed on both odd and even page (side) of the leaf, can be on the same height where the "Chapter" headings are (they don't have to go "down" for each new chapter).

What packages are my options for doing this "easily" - preferably just by changing some settings in the preamble, so afterwards each time `\chapter` (or \chapter*) is encountered, the thumb-index indicator is automatically placed?

One of the best overviews of packages I've found so far is from `texdoc`[`thumbs`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/thumbs/thumbs.pdf), version from 2014-03-09:

> - `chapterthumb`, 2005/03/10, v0.1, by Markus Kohm, available at http://mirror.ctan.org/info/examples/KOMA-Script-3/Anhang-B/source/chapterthumb.sty; unfortunately without documentation [...]
> - `eso-pic`, 2010/10/06, v2.0c by Rolf Niepraschk, available at http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic, was suggested as alternative. If I understood its code right, \AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{\put(... is used there, too. Thus I do not see its advantage. Additionally, while compiling the eso-pic test documents with TEXLive2010 worked, compiling them with Scientific WorkPlace 5.50 Build 2960 ( c MacKichan Software, Inc.) led to significant deviations of the placements (also changing from one page to the other).
> - `fancytabs`, 2011/04/16 v1.1, by Raphael Pinson, available at http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancytabs, but requires TikZ from the pgf bundle.
> - `thumb`, 2001, without file version, by Ingo Klockel, available at ftp://ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/info/examples/ltt/thumb.sty, unfortunately without documentation, [...]
> - `thumb` (a completely different one), 1997/12/24, v1.0, by Christian Holm, available at http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thumb.
> - `thumbindex`, 2009/12/13, without file version, by Hisashi Morita, available at http://hisashim.org/2009/12/13/thumbindex.html.
> - `thumb-index`, from the fancyhdr package, 2005/03/22 v3.2, by Piet van Oostrum, available at http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr.
> - `thumbpdf`, 2010/07/07, v3.11, by Heiko Oberdiek, is for creating thumbnails in a pdf document, not thumb marks (and therefore no alternative); available at http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thumbpdf.
> - `thumby`, 2010/01/14, v0.1, by Sergey Goldgaber, “is designed to work with the memoir class, and also requires PerlTEX and tikz” (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thumby), available at http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thumby.

I tried to read `texdoc fancyhdr`, but that option at least, seems to requires some more involved manual coding. So what is my best alternative for a "simple" solution? Compilable examples based on the MWE posted here would be appreciated...

Comment: Why not just use `titlesec`, your favourite drawing package and `afterpage` or something? You don't need the complex thumb stuff because you don't want thumbs.