# Changing label color for each call of the \chapter command

Tags: chapters, labels, chapterthumb

I would like to change the color of the chapter label (small rectangle box) everytime I call the command \chapter{}, possibly passing the color as an argument.

Thus the part I need to address with the argument is the command `\draw[fill=black]`.

Here a compilable example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}
%\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]  % type (section,chapter,etc...) to vary,  shape (eg display-type)
{\normalfont\fontsize{24}{26}\bfseries} % format of the chapter
{\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}     % the label 
{0pt} % separation between label and chapter-title
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[yshift=-8cm] at (current page.north west)
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay] 
    \draw[fill=black] (0,0) rectangle(35.5mm,15mm);
    \node[anchor=north east,yshift=-7.2cm,xshift=34mm,minimum height=30mm,inner sep=0mm] at (current page.north west)
    {\parbox[top][30mm][t]{15mm}{\raggedleft $\phantom{\textrm{l}}$\color{white}\chapterlabel}};  %the black l is just to get better base-line alingement
    \node[anchor=north west,yshift=-7.2cm,xshift=37mm,text width=\textwidth,minimum height=30mm,inner sep=0mm] at (current page.north west)
          {\parbox[top][30mm][t]{\textwidth}{\color{black}#1}};
   \end{tikzpicture}
  };
 \end{tikzpicture}
  \gdef\chapterlabel{}
  } % code before the title body
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

 \title{test}

 \begin{document}

 \maketitle

 \chapter{Introduction}

 \end{document}
```

I tried to pass the argument to the \chapterlabel function but didn't work. I also found a very similar question
"https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/641554/change-color-for-each-chapter" that didn't really received an answer (I tried the solution proposed but didn't work).

I would be really greatful if someone can help.

Comment: You could define colours with numbers in their names which will correspond to the chapter number. Can you make a small but compilable minimal working example?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks for your comment. I added a compilable working example. I'll try to see if I manage to do what you suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to define a series of colours with numbers in their names and the chapter will then use the colour depending on the current chapter number:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\colorlet{chapter1}{red}
\colorlet{chapter2}{blue}

\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}
%\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]  % type (section,chapter,etc...) to vary,  shape (eg display-type)
{\normalfont\fontsize{24}{26}\bfseries} % format of the chapter
{\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}     % the label 
{0pt} % separation between label and chapter-title
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[yshift=-8cm] at (current page.north west)
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay] 
    \draw[fill=chapter\the\value{chapter}] (0,0) rectangle(35.5mm,15mm);
    \node[anchor=north east,yshift=-7.2cm,xshift=34mm,minimum height=30mm,inner sep=0mm] at (current page.north west)
    {\parbox[top][30mm][t]{15mm}{\raggedleft $\phantom{\textrm{l}}$\color{white}\chapterlabel}};  %the black l is just to get better base-line alingement
    \node[anchor=north west,yshift=-7.2cm,xshift=37mm,text width=\textwidth,minimum height=30mm,inner sep=0mm] at (current page.north west)
          {\parbox[top][30mm][t]{\textwidth}{\color{black}#1}};
   \end{tikzpicture}
  };
 \end{tikzpicture}
  \gdef\chapterlabel{}
  } % code before the title body
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

 \title{test}

 \begin{document}

 \maketitle

 \chapter{Introduction}
 
  \chapter{foo}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

---

Alternatively you could colour the chapter with a user defined colour and change its definition before each chapter:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\colorlet{chapter}{red}


\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}
%\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]  % type (section,chapter,etc...) to vary,  shape (eg display-type)
{\normalfont\fontsize{24}{26}\bfseries} % format of the chapter
{\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}     % the label 
{0pt} % separation between label and chapter-title
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[yshift=-8cm] at (current page.north west)
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay] 
    \draw[fill=chapter] (0,0) rectangle(35.5mm,15mm);
    \node[anchor=north east,yshift=-7.2cm,xshift=34mm,minimum height=30mm,inner sep=0mm] at (current page.north west)
    {\parbox[top][30mm][t]{15mm}{\raggedleft $\phantom{\textrm{l}}$\color{white}\chapterlabel}};  %the black l is just to get better base-line alingement
    \node[anchor=north west,yshift=-7.2cm,xshift=37mm,text width=\textwidth,minimum height=30mm,inner sep=0mm] at (current page.north west)
          {\parbox[top][30mm][t]{\textwidth}{\color{black}#1}};
   \end{tikzpicture}
  };
 \end{tikzpicture}
  \gdef\chapterlabel{}
  } % code before the title body
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

 \title{test}

 \begin{document}

 \maketitle

\colorlet{chapter}{green}
 \chapter{Introduction}
 
\colorlet{chapter}{orange} 
  \chapter{foo}

 \end{document}
```